# CORS error with docker nginx server with react - axios

Tags: docker, nginx, cors

I have a docker server that is hosting some data. If I navigate to the URL, I can see the data no problem. However, when I run the get axios call, I get a CORS error. Is there something in Axios that I need to set up?

Error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://[myIP]:8080/myFile' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here is the docker file

```
user nginx;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
                    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    server {
        listen 80;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.access.log main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.error.log debug;

        location / {
            root /data;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That's not a dockerfile. It looks like an nginx config.

Answer (score -1):

`CROS` is for your security.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

To solve this problem you have to below step:

1- add prefix for your `backend` `apis` like `/api`

2- Change your `nginx` config to server `backend` with `proxy_pass`.https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

3- Then send your request to your `docker nginx` like this: `http://localhost:3000/api/myFile`